# Need help to crawl through multiple search result pages

Tags: python, selenium, web, web-crawler

I'm stumped in trying to make 'def get_next_page' to go through the whole search result pages. So far, it only goes up to the second page.

The main function of this code is to obtain the general info (company, product, location etc.) from all the pages.

```
 import unittest
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import time
 import re

def openPage():
   driver = webdriver.Firefox()
   driver.get("http://www.made-in-china.com/companysearch.do?subaction=hunt&order=0&style=b&code=0&word=aerator")
   elem = WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME,'search-list')))               
   analyzePage(driver)
   get_next_page(driver)


def analyzePage(driver):   
   center = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[4]') 
   companyBox=center.find_elements_by_class_name('list-node')  

for items in companyBox:   

    companyName = items.find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text.encode('utf-8')                          
    print 'companyName: ' ,companyName 

    companyLink= items.find_element_by_tag_name('h2').find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
    print 'companyLink: ', companyLink 

    companyInfo=items.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')     
    companyType=companyInfo[0].text.encode('utf-8')
    print companyType

    companyProduct=companyInfo[1].text.encode('utf-8')
    print companyProduct

def get_next_page(driver):
   page = driver.find_element_by_xpath ("/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[6]/div[1]/div")
   start_link = page.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
   for item in start_link:
     href = item.get_attribute('href')
     print href
     print"==========================================================="
     driver.execute_script(href)
     analyzePage(driver) 
return driver       


if __name__ == "__main__":
   openPage()
```

Much obliged in advance.

Edit: still stumped, any advice?

Edit: Bump again.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that clicks the button/hyperlink to go to the next page. and then get info from that page.

```
for i in range(len):
    if i>0 :
        driver.find_element_by_link_text('Next').click()
    time.sleep(5)
    #get the information here
```

Comment: Thank you, but the result still shows no difference. I've first tried it by adding it under the "get_next_page", nothing changed. I then replaced the "get_next_page" with yours, changes included, and always returned with an error: TypeError: range() integer end argument expected, got builtin_function_or_method.

Comment: It might be useful to ensure that the driver is getting the proper link and clicking it. You should see firefox open and go to the next page on click event. I'm busy right now but I'll check your code later today...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I have re-checked the links again, and they're working properly. Thinking of just manually putting each of the links in.